# KendoGrid Validation for a field doesn't get called on grid column sort/filter

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

`Validation` used  for a field  in `KendoGrid` works fine on currently being edited cell when I try to select other cell.But It `doesn't work` when I try to sort any column or use filter.
How can I enforce validation as the way normal focusout event works to any HTML element?

Code used in datasource

```
var mainDataSource={
            data :listJson   
            ,type:"json"
            ,batch:true
            ,schema: {
                model: { 
                    id: "Port_ID" 
                    ,fields:{
                            Port_ID:{type: "string",editable:false,nullable:false}
                            ,Slot1:{type:"number",editable:false}
                            ,Slot2:{type:"number",editable:false}
                            ,Type1:{type: "string",editable:true}
                            ,Type2:{type: "string",editable:false}
                            ,IsHFL:{type:"boolean",editable:false}
                           Project:{
                                type:"string"
                                ,editable:true
                                ,validation: {
                                    custom: function(input) {
                                        if(input.val()=="") {//to be added further
                                            input.attr("data-custom-msg", "Message");
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                        else
                                            return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                           ,Used_For:{ type: "string",editable:true}
                          ,Start_Date:{type:"date",editable:true}

                           }
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: Not sure what you do but it works for me. Could you show all the schema definition in you dataSource?

Comment: @OnaBai  I have my schema as above in updated question

Comment: If you cut and paste the schema there is a missing "," just before `Project` definition. If you want to see it running for checking for differences... http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XQhv4/

Comment: Thanks @OnaBai for full working grid . Actually I was looking for batch edit. Validation worked in my case but didn't prevent user from sorting  even if validation fails. http://jsfiddle.net/sanjeev537/PScWj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got feedback from telerik team on it  http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/validation/validation-call-not-triggered-on-grid-column-sort-filter.aspx

Generally speaking, preventing the binding when there are validation errors is not supported, but can be achieved with some additional code. Basically, you should use the `dataSource requestStart event` to prevent the binding with the event argument preventDefault method when there are errors e.g.

```
  requestStart: function(e){
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    if(grid.editable && !grid.editable.validatable.validate()){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```